# PHP input to MySQL database not working in Infinityfree

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I am using infinity free for my free PHP hosting and MySQL databases. I am using this code to connect to the database and that works but when I check the database it doesn't input anything. I'm pretty sure everything is right, the host, username, password, and database names are all correct but it's still not working or giving me an error code. It's just a blank page with connection successful. I'm trying to input a boolean value into my database.

DB:

[image]

And my code:

Filename: Connection.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php

$host='sql203.epizy.com';
$user='epiz_20437745';
$pass='';
$db='epiz_20437745_TwoPlayerGameDB';

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if($con) {
echo "Connection successful"; 
}
$sql="insert into TwoPlayerGame (a,s,w,d) values ('true','true','true','false')";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the error code?

Comment: also use a `;` at the end if your SQL statement.

Comment: I didn't get an error code...

Comment: Did you check logs?

Comment: Ok, so the connection is working but It's still not inputting anything. I want it to input a boolean value...am I doing it right?

Comment: When I made the database, I chose boolean for the row types but when I created it it changed them to tinyint

Comment: @MatthewSmis: that's because MySQL will [automatically] convert BOOL or BOOLEAN: `These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true`. Try a test insert using values 1, 1, 1, 0.

Comment: you're entering strings into an integer-based value, that won't work. You stated in comments: *"I didn't get an error code"* - That's because you're not checking for them @MatthewSmis

Comment: *"I'm trying to input a boolean value into my database"* - not with strings you won't.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue and after searching a lot and even asking to many instructors at udemy,i found that this was happening because of free domain and free hosting at infinityfree.net , so because of that sometimes data do not get inserted and sometime it does.So,you can buy web hosting and domains at hostinger,godaddy or any other websites if you do not want to face this issue or you can also check heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting string values into a boolean field type, which will always be TRUE.

Try, `(true,true,true,false)`

---

To help your debugging process (or always use a try catch to handle errors better...) I'd suggest using a try catch around your connection attempt

```
try {

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
    if ($con) {
        echo "Connection successful"; 
    }
    $sql = "insert into TwoPlayerGame (a,s,w,d) values ('true','true','true','false')";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = [
        'error' => $e->getCode(),
        'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        'traceString' => $e->getTraceAsString()
    ];

    // can also use error log: error_log(json_encode($error);
    var_dump($error);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I added this and my page went blank again :(

Comment: I changed the 'true' to true and it still gives me a blank page. Whats weird is that it doesn't even say "Connection successful" anymore even though it should because I didn't change that.

Comment: Echo your query and run it in phpmyadmin. Is it working fine there?

Comment: Make sure that you fix uses... or you may need to write `\Exception` to make sure it's being included.

Really should check logs.. not understanding why you are not able to get logs...